# How to perform the equivalent of AND amongst search terms

Tags: sql, postgresql, relational-division

I've built an app that displays images.  Each image can be tagged with multiple tags.  I've now added a Search box that works fine in an `OR` kind of way.  What I'm trying to figure out with PostrgreSQL is how to also let `AND` work with the entered search terms.

The key DB tables are these:

- images
- images_tags (bridge table)
- tags

Here's a simplified version of an `OR` query working correctly:

```
SELECT * from media m JOIN media_tags mt JOIN tags t USING (tag_id)
WHERE t.tag = ANY(ARRAY[${searchTerms.map(term => `'${term}'`).join(',')}]);
```

Here's an example of how this SQL code might be rendered:

```
SELECT * from media m JOIN media_tags mt JOIN tags t USING (tag_id)
WHERE t.tag = ANY(ARRAY['dog', 'cat']);
```

So, for example, if the user enters `dog cat` then every `media` record tagged with `dog` or `cat` will be returned.

But what if I wanted to perform the equivalent of `dog AND cat`?  How can I accomplish this with the Postgres flavor of SQL?

Comment: "the equivalent of dog AND cat" is not clear. [mre]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most syntactically satisfying, but also impossible to get good performance, would be to aggregate the tags, then test the the aggregate:

```
SELECT m.* from media m JOIN media_tags mt USING (something) JOIN tags t USING (tag_id)
GROUP by m.something
HAVING array_agg(t.tag) @> ARRAY['dog', 'cat'];
```

Less pretty but easier to optimize with indexes would be to use EXISTS subqueries.

```
SELECT m.* from media m where
 exists (select 1 from media_tags join tags using (tag_id) where m.id=id and tag='cat') 
 and
 exists (select 1 from media_tags join tags using (tag_id) where m.id=id and tag='dog');
```